# appnexusapi gem exception handling

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am using `appnexusapi` gem for wrapper over AppNexus API endpoints.

But I am facing various exception, and I have to handle differently for different exception.

Ex.

AppnexusApi::UnprocessableEntity: POST http://api-console.client-testing.adnxs.net/advertiser (SYNTAX): given advertiser name already exists in the system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good Question Deeps, the gem you are using is unofficial wrapper for AppNexus API endpoints. Why would you not prefer direct AppNexus RESTful endpoints?

Anyways, in Ruby you can use begin ... rescue ... end.

```
http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Exception.html
```

For more specific with AppNexus, as I know about it provides 5 types of exception as listed below.

```
NOAUTH, UNAUTH, SYNTAX, SYSTEM, INTEGRITY
```

You can catch them in following way (example I have used in project)

```
rescue_from AppnexusApi::Error do |exc|
  respond_to do |format|
    if exc.message.include?("NOAUTH")

    elsif exc.message.include? "UNAUTH"

    elsif exc.message.include? "SYNTAX"

    elsif exc.message.include? "SYSTEM"

    elsif exc.message.include? "INTEGRITY"

    else

    end
  end
end
```